# Why is my VBA ComboBox blank until I type?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I created a UserForm ComboBox with a list of items. When I run the UserForm the ComboBox appears empty until I try to type something, and only then does an item show up in the ComboBox. Is there something I'm doing wrong that makes the text in my ComboBox not show up until I type?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ListIndex after you add the items.  Assuming your ComboBox is named "cb", the following code placed in the **VBAProject->Forms->UserForm1** module will add 3 elements to the ComboBox and select the first one automatically (ComboBoxes are zero indexed).

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cb.AddItem "item 1"
    cb.AddItem "item 2"
    cb.AddItem "item 3"

    cb.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: May I add: the `cb.ListIndex` command sets the value of the combobox at the beginning. Remember that -1 will show nothing (empty combobox), 0 will show the first item indexed (in this case "item 1") and so on.